# Change a button to round programmatically

Tags: android, android-button

Having a round button in xml, I want to change its color when clicking on it. I do it with this code, but it changes to square shape again, not to the original round  shape:

```
button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Does anyone know how I can change the button's shape as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GradientDrawable shape =  new GradientDrawable();
 shape.setCornerRadius( 8 );

 // add some color
 // You can add your random color generator here
 // and set color
 if (i % 2 == 0) {
  shape.setColor(Color.RED);
 } else {
  shape.setColor(Color.BLUE);
 }

 // now find your view and add background to it
 findViewById( R.id.my_view ).setBackground(shape);
```

Comment: could you add some more information as to how the user could determine that `8` is the corner radius they are looking for?